# Elasticsearch [match] unknown token [START_OBJECT] after [created_utc]

Tags: elasticsearch

I am learning how to use elasticsearch using the 2006 dataset of reddit comments from pushshift.io.

created_utc is the field with the time a comment was created.

I am trying to get all the posts within a certain time range. I googled a bit and found out that I need to use the "range" keyword.

This is my query right now:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "range": {
                "created_utc": {
                    "gte": "1/1/2006",
                    "lte": "31/1/2006",
                    "format": "dd/MM/yyyy"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then tried using a bool query so I can match time range with edited must not = False (edited being the boolean field that tells me whether a post has been edited or not):

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "range" : {
                    "created_utc": {
                        "gte" : "01/12/2006", "lte": "31/12/2006", "format": "dd/MM/yyyy" 
                    }
                }
            },
            "must_not": {
                "edited": False
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this gave me another error that I can't figure out:

[edited] query malformed, no start_object after query name

I'd appreciate if anyone can help me out with this, thanks!

Here is my mapping for the comment if it helps:

```
{
   "comment":{
      "properties":{
         "author":{
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{
               "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "ignore_above":256
               }
            }
         },
         "body":{
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{
               "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "ignore_above":256
               }
            }
         },
         "controversiality":{
            "type":"long"
         },
         "created_utc":{
            "type":"date"
         },
         "edited":{
            "type":"boolean"
         },
         "gilded":{
            "type":"long"
         },
         "id":{
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{
               "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "ignore_above":256
               }
            }
         },
         "link_id":{
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{
               "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "ignore_above":256
               }
            }
         },
         "parent_id":{
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{
               "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "ignore_above":256
               }
            }
         },
         "score":{
            "type":"long"
         },
         "subreddit":{
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{
               "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "ignore_above":256
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get all the posts within a time range, then you must be using a range query. The problem with your query is you are using [range](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) inside a match query which is not allowed in elasticsearch, so your query should look like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "created_utc": {
          "gte": 1136074029,
          "lte": 1136076410
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Providing the fact that the **created_utc** field is saved as epoch, you must use a epoch format to query.

The second query where you want to find the posts within a range where **edited** must not false:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
          {
            "range": {
              "created_utc": {
                "gte": 1136074029,
                "lte": 1136076410
              }
            }
          }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match": {
            "edited": false
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** If your **created_utc** is stored in **dd/MM/yyyy** format then while querying you should use a [strict companion format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#built-in-date-formats), i.e. instead of 1/1/2006 you should be giving 01/01/2006.

Hope this helps !